# The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

How to change my T-SQL query so that this error doesn't occur:

> 'The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string
>   literal.'

T-SQL code:

```
Declare @Count Int = 1
While(@count <= @j)
Begin
insert into mytable
([Word])
Select ([XmlColumn].value(N'word['+Cast(@Count as nvarchar(2))+']/@Entry','nvarchar(max)'))
    from OtherTable WHERE ID=2
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You must use sql variable implicitly:

```
Declare @Count Int = 1
While(@count <= @j)
Begin
insert into mytable
([Word])
Select ([XmlColumn].value('(/word[sql:variable("@Count")]/@Entry)[1]','nvarchar(max)'))
    from OtherTable WHERE ID=2
```

Comment: Your xpath expression does not resolve to a single value. Well.. actually it does but the compiler does not know that.

Comment: this problem was in original query. anyway, the ans has been updated.

Comment: No it was not. Using `[1]` or any other number will work just fine. It failed because you introduced `sql:variable`.

Comment: `sql:variable` only works inside an XPath expression. I can't e.g. insert an entire XML DML incantation or `declare` statements from a variable.

Comment: hi, so is not possible define dynamically the output type, like varchar(value) or decimal(x,y)??

Comment: Getting this error when using implicit sql variable `Only 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal?', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean?' or 'node()*' expressions allowed as predicates, found 'xs:string ?'`

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the while loop and do the insert in one go using [`nodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx?ppud=4) to shred the XML.

```
insert into mytable([Word])
select N.value('@Entry', 'nvarchar(max)')
from OtherTable
  cross apply XmlColumn.nodes('word') as T(N)
where ID = 2
```

If `@j` is there to limit the number of rows you want to insert to `mytable` you can use this instead.

```
insert into mytable([Word])
select ID
from
  (
    select N.value('@Entry', 'nvarchar(max)') as ID, 
           row_number() over(order by T.N) as rn
    from OtherTable
      cross apply XmlColumn.nodes('word') as T(N)
    where ID = 2
  ) T
where rn <= @j
```

If you for some reason really want to use the loop then you can do like this instead.

```
while @Count <= @j
begin
  insert into mytable([Word])
  select XMLColumn.value('(/word[sql:variable("@Count")]/@Entry)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
  from OtherTable
  where ID = 2
```