# How to extract value from a XML column in SQL SERVER using a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to extract value from XML using XML value function. The path of the value, in this case, is stored in a variable. Check below script

```
DECLARE @keyPathNg NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @xml_col XML
SET @keyPathNg = '/note/to/text()'
SET @xml_col = '<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Dont forghttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408445/the-argument-1-of-the-xml-data-type-method-value-must-be-a-string-literalet me this weekend!</body></note>'
select @xml_col.value('(sql:variable("@keyPathNg"))[1]','nvarchar(max)')   ;
```

It's giving the output:

```
/note/to/text()
```

However, the output should be `Tove`

I am successfully able to extract the value when using a hardcoded path instead of the variable using the below query.

`select @xml_col.value('(/note/to/text())[1]','varchar(max)')`

As mentioned, in my case path is stored in a variable, please suggest.

I have read this answer on stack overflow [The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408445/the-argument-1-of-the-xml-data-type-method-value-must-be-a-string-literal), but as checked I am not getting the value of the variable as output, maybe I am missing some thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get SQL xml attribute value using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9231411/3484879)?

Comment: @Larnu I have tried this `select @xml_col.value('(local-name() = sql:variable("@keyPathNg"))[1]','nvarchar(max)') ` getting `SQL Error [2371] [S0001]: XQuery [value()]: 'local-name()' can only be used within a predicate or XPath selector` error. Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried the dynamic SQL (and safeky quoted) approach?

Comment: I didn't tried dynamic sql approach as I think `select @xml_col.value('(sql:variable("@keyPathNg"))[1]','nvarchar(max)')   ;` this should work. I am trying to work on dynamic sql now

Comment: `sql:variable` is a value. It is not a macro, so after the substitution the string is not xpath-parsed again.  Definetly the case for dynamic sql.